# Populate ListBoxItem Content

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I wanted to know how can I populate a ListBox dinamically. But I don't want a custom class, I just want a normal selector.

I normally do something like this with my own classes:

```
<ListBox Name="itemList" SelectionChanged="itemList_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding subtitle}"  />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What I don't know is how to simply generate the simplest thing: something like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem Name="item1" Content="First item" />
    <ListBoxItem Name="item2" Content="Second item" />
    <ListBoxItem Name="item3" Content="Third item" />
</ListBox>
```

Could you give an example of the structure? I don't know if I have to use datatemplate or what...

Thank you

[Edited: added Name property in what I need]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set up a Collection with your items in your DataContext and set it as ListBox.ItemsSource. This will then fill in your DataTemplate.

See for example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <src:Customers x:Key="customers"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource customers}" Width="250" Margin="0,5,0,10" 
       DisplayMemberPath="LastName"/>
</Grid>
```

And:

```
public class Customer
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String address)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Address = address;
    }

}

public class Customers : ObservableCollection<Customer>
{
    public Customers()
    {
        Add(new Customer("Michael", "Anderberg",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45"));
        Add(new Customer("Chris", "Ashton",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67"));
        Add(new Customer("Cassie", "Hicks",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89"));
        Add(new Customer("Guido", "Pica",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10"));
    }

}
```

Example source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.95).aspx

Edit: according to the discussion in the comments, maybe you only need a simple ItemsControl (as you don't need to retain the selected item or even better to handle multiple selection, which is what the ListBox is for).

For example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NavigateItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Label}"
                    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"                                                               
                    CommandParameter="{Binding URL}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And:

```
public class NavigateItem
 {
     public String Label { get; set; }
     public String URL { get; set; }

     public NavigateItem(String label, String url)
     {
         this.Label = label;
         this.URL = url;
     }

 }

public class NavigateItems : ObservableCollection<NavigateItem>
{
    public NavigateItems()
    {
        Add(new NavigateItem("Google", "http://www.google.com");
        Add(new NavigateItem("Bing", "http://www.bing.com");
    }
}
```

And of course setting up the ButtonCommand to navigate to the URL passed in the parameter, but that depends on how you're setting the ViewModel / bindings up.

Comment: I find it a long solution to something so simple. Well I forgot to say that I also want to set the name property of the ListBoxItems. I thought I could do something like prepare in c# a collection of listitems and binding them to the listbox. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to set the name property? I suspect you might want to access them with that handle later?

Comment: Yes, maybe I'm totally in the wrong path... I want a typical selector (of cities for example), but this has to be dynamic, I'm parsing an xml to get the list. This selection will fire an event

Comment: In that case you don't have to worry about naming the items (in fact you shouldn't really), the selection event is fired on the ListBox level! Or if you really want to handle it on the item level you should put a Button in your DataTemplate and handle its click event.

Comment: Yes, I need to handle it because the Name property will become an url parameter. So... what do you recommend to fill the listBox? I just want a selector as it is for example the one to change the accent color in the phone, but this selection will fire an event.

Comment: or a simple windows phone dropdown would be fine! Something to select with dynamic text and id. I think it's something very simple but I really can't figure out how to keep it simple!

Comment: You definitely shouldn't use a property in your view to do that. If you create a custom class as in my example, you can have a URL parameter that you can use to navigate. And also, if what you want to do is to fire an event and navigate away, then you don't really need a ListBox or a ComboBox, a simpler control like ItemsControl is all you need, filled with Buttons using a DataTemplate. I'll edit my answer to show you an example.

Comment: Thank you, I think I've undertood what you have said. It's my first application in Windows Phone. Well it's even my first application in .net and for mobiles so I'm a bit lost. I normally do web stuff.
If you know of any good tutorial just let me know. I've read a lot of tutorials but they cover very basic things and very little architecture and advanced coding.

Comment: Just say that I didn't meant I wanted to have an entire url in the Name property, just a number to use it later in the id: www.example.com?id=56. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have or want a custom class, i.e. if you just have a collection of strings, then you can assign that string collection (List, IEnumerable, string[], etc.) as the **ItemsSource** for the `ListBox` in your code-behind (or bind it from the XAML) and it will use a `TextBlock` to render that content within each `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that I also have to set the name property